# Load Json Fixture in Karma/Mocha

Tags: javascript, json, unit-testing, fixtures, karma-mocha

I am using Karma with Mocha and karma-fixture. If I go into debug when I run tests, I can see the file is loaded in the server. If I changed the config `included:true`, then I can see it's loaded on the console. The extension is changed to .js (rather than .json) and if I view source on the file (in browser window) the json is wrapped in a function -- so it seems like everything is happening as described in the [documentation](https://github.com/billtrik/karma-fixture). However, I get an error that the file cannot be found. I have included the relevant configs and errors below.

### Update 1

I was able to load the fixture with require -- which I'm using anyway to manage and load dependencies. The data is assigned to an array like this: `__json__['test/fixtures/json-data/querybrowser']`. I would still be interested in knowing why I can't use the `fixture.load()` function. I feel like I am missing a simple detail here.

Thank you!

### The configuration:

The file is located here, pathed from root of my project: `\test\fixtures\json-data\querybrowser.json`

**Karma**

```
 files: [{pattern: 'test/fixtures/{,*/}*', watched: true, included: false, served: true}]
```

**TEST spec**

```
 fixture.setBase('base/test/fixtures/json-data');
 querybrowser_json = fixture.load('querybrowser.json');
```

**The Error**

```
 Chrome 48.0.2564 (Windows 7 0.0.0) Query Browser Function Tests "before all" hook FAILED
 ReferenceError: Cannot find fixture 'base/test/fixtures/json-data/querybrowser.js' 
 at Fixture._throwNoFixture (////node_modules/karma-fixture/lib/fixture.js:141:13)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you:

1. Made sure that you're including the JSON files in both your `files` array and your `preprocessors` array inside your karma config?
2. Made sure that you have `transformPath` property defined in `jsonFixturesPreprocessor` as per https://github.com/billtrik/karma-fixture/issues/10?

I had the same issue as you but doing these things fixed it for me.

Comment: In my case I had to use `stripPrefix` in order to get it working, see a similar example here: https://github.com/incuna/incuna-surveys/commit/9f25b6d5b8cca32e23a1620b326c92b84f01222b